# trying to create an isogram using javascript (but there's something i don't understand)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements, return

so i'm fairly new to coding and i'm trying to make an isogram using javascript (without using any built-in methods because i'm still learning the basics) but i'm having difficulty grasping the logic behind this programming language. this is the code i initially used...

```
const isogram = word => {

  for(let i= 0; i< word.length; i++){ 
    for(let j = i+1; j< word.length; j++){
      if(word[i] === word[j]){
        console.log(`the letter '${word[j]}' is repeated`)
      } 
    }
  }
}

input: console.log(isogram("happy"));

//output: the letter 'p' is repeated
```

as you can see it worked fine UNITL i added an 'else-statement' and it went crazy:

```
const isogram = word => {

  for(let i= 0; i< word.length; i++){ 
    for(let j = i+1; j< word.length; j++){
      if(word[i] === word[j]){
        console.log(`the letter '${word[j]}' is repeated`)
      } else {
        console.log(`'${word}' is an isogram`)
      }
    }
  }
}

input: console.log(isogram("happy"));
//output: 'happy' is an isogram
'happy' is an isogram
'happy' is an isogram
'happy' is an isogram
'happy' is an isogram
'happy' is an isogram
'happy' is an isogram
the letter 'p' is repeated
'happy' is an isogram
'happy' is an isogram

input: console.log(isogram("cake"))
//output: 'cake' is an isogram
'cake' is an isogram
'cake' is an isogram
'cake' is an isogram
'cake' is an isogram
'cake' is an isogram
```

there's two issues with this outcome:

1. when i input a word that's NOT and isogram in this case 'happy', it prints out the else-statement which states that the word is indeed an isogram (even though happy isn't an isogram). However, it also points out the letter in the word that's repeated which in this case is the letter 'p' in 'happy'.
2. when i input a word that's an isogram like 'cake', it says it's an isogram (which is good) but it says it multiple times instead of once...

i think it's something to do with the nested 'for loops', so maybe the 'if' and the 'else' console statements are printing out for *each* character within the word instead of the word as a whole? for example for 'happy' i'm presuming this is what it's doing:

h 'happy' is an isogram //first loop
h 'happy' is an isogram //second loop
a 'happy' is an isogram //first loop
a 'happy' is an isogram //second loop
p 'happy' is an isogram //first loop
p 'happy' is an isogram //second loop
p 'happy' is an isogram //first loop
p  the letter 'p' is repeated //second loop
y 'happy' is an isogram //first loop
y 'happy' is an isogram //second loop

i also tried fixing it by replacing the else-statement with the return keyword but i came across another problem; this time when i input an isogram word it prints both statements whereas with a none-isogram word in works fine.

```
const isogram = word => {

  for(let i= 0; i< word.length; i++){ 
    for(let j = i+1; j< word.length; j++){
      if(word[i] === word[j]){
        console.log(`the letter '${word[j]}' is repeated`)
      } 
    } 
  }
  return `'${word}' is an isogram`
}

input: console.log(isogram("happy"));
//output: the letter 'p' is repeated
'happy' is an isogram

input: console.log(isogram("cake"))
//output: 'cake' is an isogram
```

overall i'm confused: why did this only start happening once i added the 'else' statement? what's the logic behind this? how can i fix it so that the console statements are only printed once? also how could i efficiently use the return keyword here?

i simply want the console to print "the letter ' ' is repeated" when it's NOT and isogram
and to print "'word' is an isogram" if the the word is an isogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I want to clarify what you mean when you say "isogram." An isogram is a word in which each letter occurs the same number of times, and it seems like you're checking specifically for "first-order isograms," where each letter appears exactly once.

With that, your last version of the code is very close. The problem there is that when it finds a letter that was repeated, it only `console.log()`s it instead of returning it. That causes it to just log to the console, continue the loop, and then `return "'${word}' is an isogram"` no matter what (I replaced the backticks with double quotes since StackOverflow doesn't seem to allow nested backticks?). If you want it to terminate as soon as it finds a repeated letter, you can simply either `return "the letter '${word[j]}' is repeated"` or `return` right after the `console.log()`.

```
if(word[i] === word[j]){
    return `the letter '${word[j]}' is repeated`;
}
```

```
if(word[i] === word[j]){
    console.log(`the letter '${word[j]}' is repeated`);
    return;
}
```

As for the `else` version, it didn't just "start happening once i added the 'else' statement." In an if-else statement, if the `if` block runs, then the `else` block doesn't run. If the `if` block doesn't run, then the `else` block runs. With "happy", the `if` block only runs once when it encounters the two 'p's because `word[i] === word[j]` is true, so naturally, every single other loop iteration will run the `else` block because none of the other combinations of letters match.

**i = 0:** | h === a: false | h === p: false | h === p: false | h === y: false |

**i = 1:** | a === p: false | a === p: false | a === y: false |

**i = 2:** | p === p: ***true*** | p === y: false |

**i = 3:** | p === y: false |

**i = 4**  |(nothing here since j starts as 5) |

Comment: So from my understanding, using 'return' prevents the function from executing (so it stops the loop once the letter's found) and using console.log doesn't actually return a value, it only logs the statement that I'd written onto the console over and over again? Also thank you so much for the detailed response, the code finally works!

Comment: @Decodeme Yeah, that's exactly right. As soon as you hit return inside of a function, it ends the function's execution. Glad you got it working—can you mark the answer as correct?

Comment: Of course, done :)